# Abstract generic class explanation

Tags: java, generics, extends

I'm reviewing some code and trying to understand the logic of the code below, but sample like below is just too much for me:

```
public abstract class NewPage1<T extends NewPage1> extends SuperPage<T> implements Interface1<T>, Interface2<T>{    
    ...
}
```

Can you please explain to me what's just happened there? Maybe some use case of this code? Why This generic class is a type of `T` which extends himself and then again it extends some other generic class... I just can't find any logical/practical explanation for this. I would be appreciated for figuring it out.

Comment: This declaration of the type variable is wrong, in that it is currently using a raw bound: it should be `NewPage1<T extends NewPage1<T>>`.

Comment: if you are reviewing existing code, aren't there any other classes which use or extend from NewPage so you can have a better understanding about what T can be. If there really is an interface called Interface1 or Interface2 then maybe it is better to get rid of this code or dependency :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any context it's difficult to say, but it seems to be a pattern used when you try to code a hierarchy with fluent operations (methods that return the same object in order to chain calls).

Let's consider the following example:

```
  abstract class Animal {
     Animal eat() { /* ... */ return this; }
     Animal poo() { /* ... */ return this; }
  }
  abstract class FootedAnimal extends Animal {
     FootedAnimal walk()  { /*...*/ return this; }
  }
  class Dog extends FootedAnimal {
      Dog bark() { /* ... */ return this; }   
  }
```

With this class, you can chain methods:

```
   new Dog()
   .bark()  // returns Dog
   .walk()  // returns FootedAnimal
   .eat()   // returns Animal
   .poo()   // returns Animal
   .eat();  // returns Animal
```

But, due to the returning type of the methods in `Animal`, you can't do this:

```
   new Dog()
   .eat()    // returns Animal
   .poo()    // returns Animal
   .bark();  // <- bark() does not exist in Animal !!!
```

This can be addressed making the abstract class generic:

```
  abstract class Animal<S extends Animal<S>> {
     S eat() { /* ... */ return (S)this; }
     S poo() { /* ... */ return (S)this; }
  }
  abstract class FootedAnimal<S extends FootedAnimal<S>> extends Animal<S> {
     S walk() { /* ... */ return (S)this; }
  }
  class Dog extends FootedAnimal<Dog> {
      Dog bark() { /* ... */ return this; }   
  }
```

Now the methods of `Animal` and `FootedAnimal` return the type `S`, that is `Dog` for the class `Dog`, so that you can freely chain methods of any level of the hierarchy.

```
   new Dog()
   .eat()    // returns S=Dog
   .poo()    // returns S=Dog
   .bark()   // returns Dog
   .walk()   // returns S=Dog
   .eat();   // returns S=Dog
```

Comment: thanks, man. I think you got the point in the context of all other code.